# How to filter a Pandas dataframe to show rows of top categories?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `movies` containing thousands of movie data, it basically looks something like this:

```
|   | MovieTitle        | Genre     |   Studio             |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | Tomorrowland      | action    | Buena Vista Studios  |
| 1 | White House Down  | action    | Sony                 |
| 2 | Doctor Dolittle   | adventure | Fox                  |
```

I'm trying to filter the dataframe to show movies by studios that produced 10 or more movies. I tried obtaining top studios using this code:

```
top10 = (movies.groupby('Studio').size() > 10)
```

The above correctly returns a series of studios and a boolean indicating if they have 10+ movies, something like this:

```
| Studio               |       |
--------------------------------
| Art House Studios    | False |
| Buena Vista Studios  | True  |
| DreamWorks           | True  |
| Lionsgate            | False |
```

So, I wanted to retrieve studios that have a `True` from the above series to use them to subset the `movies` dataframe using `isin()`:

```
top10 = top10[top10 == True].axes
print(top10)
```

The above print command outputs something like this:

```
Index(['Buena Vista Studios', 'WB', 'Fox', 'Universal', 'Sony',
   'Paramount Pictures', 'New Line Cinema', 'Pacific Data/DreamWorks',
   'DreamWorks', 'MiraMax'],
   dtype='object', name='Studio')
```

Finally, I want to use the above list to filter `movies` dataframe:

```
movies[movies['Studio'].isin(top10)]
```

This results in an *empty dataframe*. However, using the output list directly like this:

```
movies[movies['Studio'].isin(['Buena Vista Studios', 'WB', 'Fox', 'Universal', 'Sony',
   'Paramount Pictures', 'New Line Cinema', 'Pacific Data/DreamWorks',
   'DreamWorks', 'MiraMax'])]
```

does return the correct filtered dataframe. So `top10` doesn't behave like a list, though `type(top10)` does indicate it's a list.

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a simpler way of filtering the data frame to show movies by studios who created 10 or more movies?

Comment: `top10` is an index object, not a list. However, you can pass it to the list constructor (`list(top10)`) or call `.values` on it to get it as a list or listlike object

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for your comment. I tried both `list(top10)` and `top10.values` .. both don't filter the dataframe correctly when used in `isin()`.

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to filter your original dataframe and only have the studio's that have have produced the most movies? within a top 10 cat.

Comment: @Datanovice Yes, basically I want to filter the original dataframe to show only the records of studios that produced 10 or more movies.

Comment: @Datanovice Hmm ... the expression `df.groupby(['MovieTitle','Studio'])['MovieTitle'].transform('size') > 10` returns a series that is all `False` (for all rows), thus the resulting dataframe is empty :/

Comment: @A.Genedy sorry my fault :`df.loc[df.groupby(['Studio'])['MovieTitle'].transform('size') > 10] ` are you able to share a bigger dataset 10 rows that will help its hard to guess this way.

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks! That works fine ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding as an answer :

using `transform` lets you run groupby operations without modifying the index, we can use that to leverage your request of the top 10 studios by movies.

we can use `.loc` to return this as a condition.

`df.loc[df.groupby(['Studio'])['MovieTitle'].transform('size') > 10]`

in regards to your code, if you want a list of studios to pass into a list then you could use

```
studios = top10[top10 == True]['Studio'].unique().tolist()
```

then use `.isin`

```
df[df['Studios'].isin(studios)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the code `top10 = top10[top10 == True].axes` to 
`top10 = top10.index[top10 == True]` will solve the problem without changing anything else.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes my code in the question indeed. However, I like @Datanovice solution in the comments to my question more as it involves less steps and is much simpler.